# C++ string literal type and declaration

Tags: c++, string

Two types of the declaration:

```
char* str1 = "string 1";
```

and

```
char str2[] = "string 2";
```

my compiler doesn't allow me to use first declaration with a error
incorrect conversion from const char[8] to char*. looks okay,
the version like this:

```
const char* str1 = "string 1";
```

passed by compiler.

please clarify my understanding.
I believed that if we declare both versions e.g. in main(), 
first one (const char*) - the only pointer will be allocated on the stack and initialized with some address in data segment.
second version (char[]) - whole array of symbols will be placed on the stack

as far as I see string literal does now always have a const char[] type.
is a using of const char* depricated? for C compatibility only?

where each version will store the string ?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Any reason you expect them to behave identical? This is not about C.

Comment: That's funny, `"string 1"` is a `const char[9]`, not a `const char[8]`.

Comment: @aschepler Not funny - normal. There is a trailing 0 character that makes up the 9...

Comment: There is no requirement for a stack. And what is your actual problem? That string literals are `const char []`?

Comment: I got the number of symbols in a message from the memory :) sorry, haven't ability to compile right now, my mistake , forgot '\0'

Comment: using a `const char*` is not deprecated.  the thing that was deprecated(C++03) and made non standard(C++11) is `char *  = "bad";`

Comment: if we get a type of "string" this won't return const char*. this is conat char[]
so my second question is actual - where is a stored both versions

Comment: To explain the char[] stuff: "string 2" is still a string literal and thus still of type char const*. But you do not assign it to a pointer, but use it to initialise an array (that will receive the same size as the string literal). So the literal is copied into the char array (at least in theory, compiler might optimise here...).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> char* str1 = "string 1";
> ```

This is deprecated as of C++98, and is ill-formed as of C++11, as  a string literal can't be modified. Modifying it would result in undefined behavior.

To avoid this, the standard prohibits assigning it to a modifiable `char` pointer, as it *might* be modified later on without the programmer realizing that he/she shouldn't have modified it.

> ```
> char str2[] = "string 2";
> ```

Yes, this allocated an array of characters, whereas each character is stored on the stack.

> ```
> const char* str1 = "string 1";
> ```

This isn't deprecated, it is the recommended way (only way) to assign a string literal to a `char` pointer. Here, `str1` is points to `const` chars, i.e. they can't be modified. Thus it is safe to use it somewhere, as the compiler will enforce that the `char`s will never be modified.

Here, `str1` is stored on the stack, pointing to a string literal, which may or may not be stored in read-only memory (this is implementation defined).

Comment: "`char* str1 = "string 1";` This is deprecated as of C++11" No. This is deprecated in C++98 and is _ill-formed_ as of C++11.

Answer (score 2):

`char str2[] = "string 2";`

`"string 2"` is string literal `const char[9]` stored in read-only memory.

`char str2[]` will allocate char array (of size deducted from initializer size) in read-write memory.

`=` will use the string literal to initialize the char array (doing `memcpy` of the `"string 2"` content).

I mean in principle. The actual machine code produced with optimizations may differ, setting up `str2` content by less trivial means than `memcpy` from string literal.

`char* str1 = "string 1";` - here you are trying to get the actual string literal memory address, but that one is `const`, so you shouldn't assign/cast it to `char *`.

`const char* str1` should work OK, casting from `const char[]` to `const char *` is valid (they are almost the same thing, unless you have access to original array size during compilation, then the pointer variant is size-less dumb-down version).

Comment: so the version const char* is a really pointer to string literal in data segment. second version - char[] is an array just initialized from string literal by copying chars from right hand value. is it correct?